# appending html string with .append() does not work?

Tags: jquery

I am rather new to jquery, so please bear with me.  I have created an HTML page containing a number of hooks to which I want to append new elements.  Appending a string works as expected:

```
$(theParentNode).append ("blurb1");
```

But appending HTML does not:

```
$(theParentNode).append ("<b>blurb2</b>");
```

When I check the resulting DOM there are no children of the parent node.  And finally, when
I try this:

```
$(theParentNode).append ("blurb1");
$(theParentNode).append ("<b>blurb2</b>");
$(theParentNode).append ("blurb3");
```

only the first child node shows up in the parent's list of children.  A final experiment involved adding a "span" instead of a "b" element.  In that case I get an error from jquery: div is null, line 6443 of jquery-1.7.2.js

I must be overlooking something very basic, but still it's difficult why it doesn't work since append is supposed to take html strings...  Thanx for any help!

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/hMfQe/... please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo which replicates your problem yourself. What kind of element is `theParentNode`? If we cannot replicate the problem, we cannot help you. The code you posted "works".

Comment: The parent node is a div.  It is very difficult to show the code, since it is generated by php from a template by an xsl style sheet.  The code to be inserted is generated by further xsl transformations.

Comment: The parent node is an empty div, I should have added that; it has an id that allows it to be referred to in order to insert new contents.  To rule out problems with the code to be inserted, I replaced the code that is to process the hook by a very simple version that just adds text or html.  text works, html doesn't.  As you can see now, when I add a "span" I get a message from jquery.  It happens when the html is being processed.  Is this a hint?

Comment: Where is your jQuery code ?? Is it in a `$(document).ready(function() { }`

Comment: It is called indirectly from within a $(window).load.  For some reason I cannot remember I couldn't use $(document).ready.  Most of the code was written 1,5 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try referring to it by it's ID:-

For example:-

`<div id='MyDiv'></div>`

You'll need to use:-

`$('#MyDiv').append("<b>blurb2</b>");`

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing, although the parent node cannot be referred to statically since it is itself dynamically generated by a complex process.  The problem is NOT that I cannot append anything to the parent node: appending text works well.  It is that I cannot append html.  I suspect that it has something to do with importing the html elements that are generated by append ().  When I append elements created by document.createElement, they will be shown as expected!

Comment: Can you do a view source and paste some code somewhere we can have a look at. Into jsfiddle.net would be good.

Comment: Unfortunately the current code is some 2000 lines of javascript, which is closely tied with a lot of php and xsl stylesheets.  I will have to work on a shorter example.